# Android Offline Maps - OSMDroid

Tags: android, maps, offline, osmdroid, wms

I'm trying to make an Android application that lets you download map tiles for a particular bounding box (multiple zoom levels) and use them when the device isn't connected to network.

I'm using **OSMDroid** as the maps library. These are the things that I have tried -

1. **Cache Manager** - Using this takes a very long time to download map data for even a small bounding box and one zoom level. Sample code -

   ```
   CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager(map);
   cacheManager.downloadAreaAsync(this, new BoundingBox(85, 21, 84, 20), 15, 15);
   ```
2. **Mapsforge** - I found a couple of sample projects using Mapsforge to download map tiles for offline use. But that didn't help me either.
3. **MOBAC** - Couldn't find anything concrete.

I want to be able to download map data and load those tiles in offline mode. Also, there are lot of legal issues related to using certain map sources.

1. **What are the map sources that we can use without worrying about legal issues?**
2. **How can I download base map data and any overlay layers(kml, geojson, wms, etc) for a particular bounding box?**
3. **What are the best Open Source libraries for Offline Maps?**

Thanks!!

**UPDATE :**

So, I've used MapProxy to cache tiles for a BBox and zoom levels. I'm trying to use osmdroid to render these tiles.

I've stored these png tiles in (/sdcard/osmdroid/tiles). The [documentation](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles#using-offline-tile-archives) says something about storing it as cache.db. The set of tiles I have cached are png images. **How do I store them in the required format**?

Secondly, **how can I set the Tile Source to use these offline tiles**?

Thanks again!

Comment: You have to setup your own server where the app can download the offline stuff from generated with MOBAC. As far as i know the download servers of openstreetmap and mapsforge only allow small traffic